# The probability that at least one missile will hit.

Tags: probability, combinations

[This is is the question I want to solve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYo3f.png)
I think the answer to question is 7/9 but the answers in my book is showing  otherwise. What have I done wrong? I got the answer 7/9 my the formula 3C1*1/3*(2.3)^2+3C2*(1/3)^2*2/3+3C3*(1/3)^3.

Comment: For part A think about the times a missle can hit *at least once* out of the 3 attempts  (i.e, once, twice or all three times).

Comment: that is what I did and I get the answer 19/27. which seems to be correct.

Comment: @SaugatAwale: What is wrong with $\frac{19}{27}$ then?

Comment: @zoli it seems that is the correct answer. In the answer section of my book it was written 1-(1/3)^5 which I assume to a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A(n)$ denote the event that no missile hits the target when we fire n missiles. $Q$ denotes the probability measure.
$Q(A(3))=(1-P)^3$, and $Q(A(3)^c)=1-(1-P)^3$.

$A(3)^c$ is the event that at least one missile hits the target when we fire 3 missiles.

More generally, if we fire n missiles, we have 
$Q(A(n))=(1-P)^n$

Therefore, if we fire n missiles, the probability that at least one missile among the n ones reach the target is 
$Q(A(n)^c)=1-(1-P)^n$.

We want $Q(A(n)^c)=0.9$, therefore we must solve

$$1-(1-P)^n=0.9$$
taking the log, we have
$$nlog(1-P)=log(0.1)$$
or 
$$n=\frac{log(0.1)}{log(1-P)}\approx 5.7$$
Therefore we must choose $n=6$

Comment: but log(0.1)/log(2/3) = 5.67 hence the answer 6 right?

Comment: Your exercise says $P=\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: The probability that it hits the target = 1/3. the probability that it misses = 2/3 .According to your denotations and assignments Q(A(3)) = (2/3)^3 and Complement of Q(A(3))= 1-(2/3)^3 = 19/27 which is the answer to the first question.

Comment: If you are still confused think of it this way. You got the answer 3 right? That means if we fire the missile the three times the probability that at least one will hit the target should have been greater that 0.9. But that is not the case as we can see in number one. You can try it the other way round you get the probability 19/27 that you hit the target if you fire three times. So I firmly believe in this case P = 2/3 and it works also when you do the other way round. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I apologize I misread , I thought that P was the probability that we miss the target. I fixed it !